# Determine whether an event ever occurred in a time series, by group (in R)

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
> a = data.frame(date = rep(c("20160101", "20160201", "20160301", "20160401"), 4),
+                person = c(rep("Bill", 4), rep("Jim", 4), rep("Sarah", 4), rep("Katie", 4)),
+                purchased_product = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
+                ever_purchased_previously = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
> a
       date person purchased_product ever_purchased_previously
1  20160101   Bill                 0                         0
2  20160201   Bill                 0                         0
3  20160301   Bill                 1                         0
4  20160401   Bill                 0                         1
5  20160101    Jim                 0                         0
6  20160201    Jim                 0                         0
7  20160301    Jim                 0                         0
8  20160401    Jim                 1                         0
9  20160101  Sarah                 1                         0
10 20160201  Sarah                 0                         1
11 20160301  Sarah                 1                         1
12 20160401  Sarah                 1                         1
13 20160101  Katie                 0                         0
14 20160201  Katie                 1                         0
15 20160301  Katie                 0                         1
16 20160401  Katie                 0                         1
```

I'm looking to calculate the ever_purchased_previously column from the purchased_product column, but need to do so by group (in this, case by "person").  Also notice that ever_purchased_previously is only equal to 1 the month after the purchase (i.e., not in the same month).  Can assume the data will be ordered by date.

I have been attempting to come up with a few solutions, looking at the minimum date where purchased_product = 1, and also with the na.locf function from the zoo package, but no luck so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `purchased_product` column consists only of 0, 1 elements, `cummax` is better choice than `na.locf`

```
#data.table way
library(data.table)
setDT(a)
a[, ever:=cummax(shift(purchased_product, fill=0)), by=person]

#dplyr way
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(ever=cummax(lag(purchased_product, default=0)))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you cummax is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use the `date` column since they're ordered by date:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(a)){
  n <- min(which(a$person==a$person[i]))
  if(sum(a$purchased_product[n:i])>0) a$ever_purchased_previously[i] <- 1
  if(a$ever_purchased_previously[i]==1 & a$purchased_product[i]==1) a$ever_purchased_previously[i] <- 0
}

a
```

> ```
>        date person purchased_product ever_purchased_previously
> 1  20160101   Bill                 0                         0
> 2  20160201   Bill                 0                         0
> 3  20160301   Bill                 1                         0
> 4  20160401   Bill                 0                         1
> 5  20160101    Jim                 0                         0
> 6  20160201    Jim                 0                         0
> 7  20160301    Jim                 0                         0
> 8  20160401    Jim                 1                         0
> 9  20160101  Sarah                 1                         0
> 10 20160201  Sarah                 0                         1
> 11 20160301  Sarah                 1                         0
> 12 20160401  Sarah                 1                         0
> 13 20160101  Katie                 0                         0
> 14 20160201  Katie                 1                         0
> 15 20160301  Katie                 0                         1
> 16 20160401  Katie                 0                         1
> ```